# Explain how doit() function works in rshd.c

Tags: linux, c, system-calls, rsh

I want to know how rsh runs any command. I am using **netkit-rsh-0.17** package. My OS is **centOS**.

In rshd directory, `rshd.c` performs the task to run any command on server.
In this file, `doit()` is the main function who performs all the task.

**Questions**,

1. What `pwd->pw_dir`, `pwd->pw_uid`, `pwd->pw_shell` means in this code?
2. What `pv` does in this.

Explain me by using `rsh localhost ulimit -n` command.

**doit()**

```c
static void
doit(struct sockaddr_in *fromp)
{
    char cmdbuf[ARG_MAX+1];
    const char *theshell, *shellname;
    char locuser[16], remuser[16];
    struct passwd *pwd;
    int sock = -1;
    const char *hostname;
    u_short port;
    int pv[2], pid, ifd;

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);

    alarm(60);
    port = getint();
    alarm(0);

    if (port != 0) {
        int lport = IPPORT_RESERVED - 1;
        sock = rresvport(&lport);
        if (sock < 0) {
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "can't get stderr port: %m");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (port >= IPPORT_RESERVED) {
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "2nd port not reserved\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fromp->sin_port = htons(port);
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)fromp,
                sizeof(*fromp)) < 0) {
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "connect second port: %m");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

#if 0
    /* We're running from inetd; socket is already on 0, 1, 2 */
    dup2(f, 0);
    dup2(f, 1);
    dup2(f, 2);
#endif

    getstr(remuser, sizeof(remuser), "remuser");
    getstr(locuser, sizeof(locuser), "locuser");
    getstr(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "command");
    if (!strcmp(locuser, "root")) paranoid = 1;

    hostname = findhostname(fromp, remuser, locuser, cmdbuf);

    setpwent();
    pwd = doauth(remuser, hostname, locuser);
    if (pwd == NULL) {
        fail("Permission denied.\n", 
             remuser, hostname, locuser, cmdbuf);
    }

    if (chdir(pwd->pw_dir) < 0) {
        chdir("/");
        /*
         * error("No remote directory.\n");
         * exit(1);
         */
    }


    if (pwd->pw_uid != 0 && !access(_PATH_NOLOGIN, F_OK)) {
        error("Logins currently disabled.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    (void) write(2, "\0", 1);
    sent_null = 1;

    if (port) {
        if (pipe(pv) < 0) {
            error("Can't make pipe.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)  {
            error("Can't fork; try again.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid) {
            close(0); 
            close(1);
            close(2); 
            close(pv[1]);
            stderr_parent(sock, pv[0], pid);
            /* NOTREACHED */
        }
        setpgrp();
        close(sock); 
        close(pv[0]);
        dup2(pv[1], 2);
        close(pv[1]);
    }
    theshell = pwd->pw_shell;
    if (!theshell || !*theshell) {
        /* shouldn't we deny access? */
        theshell = _PATH_BSHELL;
    }

#if BSD > 43
    if (setlogin(pwd->pw_name) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "setlogin() failed: %m");
    }
#endif
#ifndef USE_PAM
    /* if PAM, already done */
    if (setgid(pwd->pw_gid)) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "setgid: %m");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (initgroups(pwd->pw_name, pwd->pw_gid)) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "initgroups: %m");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif
    if (setuid(pwd->pw_uid)) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "setuid: %m");
        exit(1);
    }
    environ = envinit;

    strncat(homedir, pwd->pw_dir, sizeof(homedir)-6);
    homedir[sizeof(homedir)-1] = 0;

    strcat(path, _PATH_DEFPATH);

    strncat(shell, theshell, sizeof(shell)-7);
    shell[sizeof(shell)-1] = 0;

    strncat(username, pwd->pw_name, sizeof(username)-6);
    username[sizeof(username)-1] = 0;

    shellname = strrchr(theshell, '/');
    if (shellname) shellname++;
    else shellname = theshell;

    endpwent();
    if (paranoid) {
        syslog(LOG_INFO|LOG_AUTH, "%s@%s as %s: cmd='%s'",
           remuser, hostname, locuser, cmdbuf);
    }

    /*
     * Close all fds, in case libc has left fun stuff like 
     * /etc/shadow open.
     */
    for (ifd = getdtablesize()-1; ifd > 2; ifd--) close(ifd);

    execl(theshell, shellname, "-c", cmdbuf, 0);
    perror(theshell);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Read the manual page on `exec(3)`. It replaces the currently running program with a new one.

Comment: I read that, but how can this perform whole task in above function by using above command written in question, please.

Comment: This is a freshman-level systems programming question. All of the functions in the above code have `man` pages.

Comment: Don't copy this code. Look at the bit where it closes all the fds: that should obviously happen before the setuid, or it's a waste of time from a security point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`struct passwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pwd.h.html) is documented in POSIX, in `pwd.h`. It is a structure used to store the `/etc/passwd` entries for a given user. The three you mention are these:

> - `uid_t pw_uid`
>     Numerical user ID.
> - `char *pw_dir`
>     Initial working directory. (Home directory.)
> - `char *pw_shell`
>     Program to use as shell. (Default shell for the user.)

The function `doauth` referenced in the code above probably either calls `getpwent` or simulates that to fill in the appropriate values for the user on the remote system.

`pv` is pair of file descriptors representing connected pipes, set up by [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html). `pv[0]` is the "read side", `pv[1]` the "write side". Anything written to `pv[1]` can be read from `pv[0]`.

In the code above, the parent process does:

```
close(pv[1]);
stderr_parent(sock, pv[0], pid);
```

which closes the write side, and, I'm guessing, wires the read side to (one of) the sockets used to communicate between the hosts.

The child process on the other hand does this:

```
close(pv[0]);    // close the read side
dup2(pv[1], 2);  // clone the write side to fd n° 2 (stderr)
close(pv[1]);    // close the original write side (now only
                 // writable through fd n° 2
```

So basically, the child's `stderr` stream is now connected to a network stream back to the client.

The rest of the code essentially sanitizes the environment (environment variables and working directory), checks permissions, sets the appropriate `uid`/`gid` and finally executes the command that the user wanted to run using [`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html) via a shell. The actual command run on the remote system will be something like `/bin/sh -c <user command string>`.
So with your example, assuming for example that your user's shell in `/etc/passwd` is `/bin/bash`, the `execl` call will result in running this:

```
/bin/bash -c 'ulimit -n'
```

(Quotes since the user command is a single argument in the `execl` call, it is not tokenized.)

Comment: Execellent explanation. I was waiting for such nice explanation for long time from this forum. Thanks. Now I try to connect this solution from my main problem. That is on given link http://serverfault.com/questions/487426/why-ulimit-shows-different-outputs   If I will find any doubt, I will contact with you. +1 for your explanation.

Comment: @ jhamb Note that rshd is the service. That means what Mat calls the "remote user" is what the code calls locuser. Similarly, the remote system is the one running locally this very code.